# auto close a popup using c#

Tags: c#, ssis

I am having a little problem with my C# code. The script I have, finds a specific window header popup and then close it. They are 2 separate scripts, and I want to merge them in one. (Cant add image as not enough rep yet).

The code where my problem is, is follows:

```
public void Main()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<IntPtr, string> window in OpenWindowGetter.GetOpenWindows())
        {
            IntPtr handle = window.Key;
            string title = window.Value;

        //    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", handle, title);
            if (title == Dts.Variables["User::WindowText"].Value.ToString())
            {
                // close window
                MessageBox.Show(title);
                SendMessage(title, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);

            }
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

On send message the error says:

```
The best overloaded method match for '*NameSpace*.ScriptMain.SendMessage(int, uint, int, int) has some invalid arguments.
```

The original code for closing error is at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22257/Find-and-Close-the-Window-using-Win-API

Comment: I found the error. Read the whole code, when I declared SendMessage my first argument's data type was int but title was IntPtr, so just had to change the data type when declaring SendMessage. Thanks all anyways :)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035700/using-enumwindows-to-find-specific-title-and-closing-it